# Displaying very complex table view cells makes scrolling laggy

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, xcode6

What is the best way to display very complex "cards" in a table view?

I am displaying views inside table view cells to get a card effect.
On these views I have multiple buttons, labels, other views and nearly always another tableview.

These views were all designed in their own View file (.xib). 
I populate an array containing all of these views in the order I'd like to display them and then when cellForRowAtIndexPath gets called I simply add these views as subviews to a view all ready on the cell. Each of these cards can resize their cell at will and each card has a different, dynamically calculated height.

Everything works perfectly but scrolling lags immensely. Scrolling through these "cards" aren't smooth at all, it is jumpy an laggy. Also if I rotate the device the rotation animation has at most 10 frames (meaning it is very laggy as well).

What is the best and the correct way to display these "cards" (views with a lot of UI components) in the tableview cells?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use Xcode's profiler to determine where your processor is losing most of its cycles, then optimize that. Without specifics, this question is very vague.

Comment: Another thing to look into is reusing views. It's much more efficient to reuse a view and update its content/label values than continuously create and destroy views as you scroll through a list.

Comment: I am reusing them. And furthermore, I mostly display only one view of each type thus there's no reusing necessary.

Comment: Ok it was the shadows I applied to the "cards"